# Модуль регистрации и комментариев для Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal

На сайте я хочу внести систему комментариев и регистрации с пользовательскими полями. 
В модуле регистрации, мне нужна будет капча, а так же несколько полей, одно из них - это чекбокс о том, что бы подписаться на рассылку.
В системе комментариев основное требование - это возможность менять количество символов для отправки сообщения. Возможность выбора какой материал комментировать
Какие вы используете модули для реализации подобного функционала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарии это встроенная функция в друпал 7.

Для редактирования длинны длинны комментариев имеется [**модуль**](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_length_limiter), однако стабильной версии для д7 у него нет, поэтому его использование нужно тестировать или заниматься этим в ручную.

Для добавлении капчи к формам можно воспользоваться этим [**модулем**](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha).

Для возможности выбора какой материал можно комментировать на каждом ноде есть возможность отключения комментариев в ручную при создании.

Comment: А возможность оставлять комментарии через определённый промежуток времени т.е. 1 комментарий через 5 минут. Можно сделать встроенными средствами?

Comment: Для этого можно использовать [**node module**](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) и в настройках ролей и их разрешений указать промежуток времени между последним и новым комментарием. Как альтернативу можно так же использовать модуль [**Honeypot**](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot). Если у меня получилось ответить на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, пометьте ответ как верный.